# Offline Document Organizer

Tags: windows, open-source, pdf, file-management, document-management

I'm looking for an **open source** program to organize my documents. One program that seems to meet all my needs is [paperless-ngx](https://docs.paperless-ngx.com/), but it is not a local program. Another one that comes very close is [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/), but this is a program more focused on citations.

Something important for me is that the program is local and that it works on Windows. It's for personal use and I don't want to have to use Docker or something similar.
Other programs that seem to satisfy what I'm looking for are for example [papermerge](https://www.papermerge.com/), [Docspell](https://docspell.org/), but these are server type.

I need a program which can:

- Store and index of documents (PDF -- If it supports other formats it would be great, but in the end I can convert to PDF)
- Organize files into folders.
- Tags, manual descriptions
- Find documents by tags, name, date, description
- Text is extracted from all files (OCR) to be available for full-text search.

In addition to being a local program, it is very important that I can search in my files, these are already organized in folders, I would like to improve this organization now with tags, descriptions and observations.

I managed to find local programs that are very good for searching within documents, but I can't organize my files, they are only for searching. For exemple [Paperwork](https://www.openpaper.work/) and [Docfecher](https://docfetcher.sourceforge.io/en/index.html)

Comment: What have you looked at, and what were their failings? Have you looked for _any_ (e.g., non-FOSS) solutions, and then perhaps asked alternativeto.net about alternatives to it?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've amended my question to include a little more information. I found programs like Paperwork, but it works more like a search engine than a way for me to organize my documents.